# How to get the IDs of nodes inside HTMLEditor, JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I wish to remove some of the control buttons from HTMLEditor, since I do not need them. for that I need to reach the desired node. How can I know the IDs of nodes inside HTMLEditor? Please see the following. Thank you!

```
public class myApp extends Application {

    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        Parent root = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("myApp.fxml")); //this fxml has HTMLEditor named htmlEditor.
        Scene scene = new Scene(root);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();

        Node someControlInsideHtmlEditor = root.lookup("#htmlEditor").lookup("#what_Is_The_ID_of_This_someControlInsideHtmlEditor")
    }
}
```

Comment: hello everyone! Happy New Year! 

I wish to bring again the same question as no one answered it. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5):

- Download [Scenic View](http://fxexperience.com/scenic-view/) from [here](http://fxexperience.com/downloads/ScenicView-8.0.0-developer-preview-4.zip)
- Add this to your application's class path
- Add the following line to your start() method's end:

> ScenicView.show(scene);
>
> Run the application
>
> Two windows will pop up: the primaryStage with the HTMLEditor and Scenic View's Stage
>
> Now you can visit every node of the Scene Graph. Open the tree at the left pane, and select a Node from the HTMLEditor. You can access the controls by their CSS class.

For example, open HTMLEditor -> ToolBar -> HBox, and select the first Button. Look at "styleClass" in the "Node Details" at the right side. You will need "html-editor-cut". It can be used with this code:

> Button cutButton = (Button) root.lookup(".html-editor-cut");

Answer (score 0):

don't know if you're still looking for this answer. In Java 8, and HTMLEditor only has one child, which is a GridPane. The first two children of that are the ToolBars, the third is a WebView. Remove the first two children from the gridpane to do the formatting you want. Does that help?

Comment: can't we access other children by calling "lookupall()"?